# Java exception error for Disemvowel

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Disemvowel
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word = stdin.next();
    String disemvoweledWord = "";
    int len = word.length();

    for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++) 
    {

        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        if (!(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u'))
        {
            disemvoweledWord = disemvoweledWord+ch;

        }
    }
    System.out.println(disemvoweledWord);
}
```

Trying to make a program the takes vowels out of an entered word but I am getting a exception error I am not sure why..

EDIT: This is the error
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at r6.Disemvowel.main(Disemvowel.java:20)"

Comment: Surely you're going to tell us what the error message is, right?

Comment: added in question

Comment: For loops should loop until the index is less than the length, not less than or equal to. So not `for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++)` but rather `for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you!